# How do I exit a window manager (StumpWM) and X11 session launched with `dbus-launch --exit-with-x11 stumpwm`?

Tags: x11, window-manager, stumpwm

I have in my `.xinitrc` the line `dbus-launch --exit-with-session stumpwm`. Occasionally, I'll want to kill everything that has to do with X, get back to a terminal, and start over.

If I `ps aux | grep stumpwm` and kill the [StumpWM](https://stumpwm.github.io/) process, the window manager dies, but everything with x11 still works. I can type in the window that currently has focus but I can't change focus or do any other window management.

I also tried `sudo kill -9 startx`, no effect. I noticed another "x" process, `xinit`, and killing that also had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out 2 solutions to my problem.

First, to kill the graphics, the process that I realized I needed to kill was an `Xorg` process. I found that with `ps aux` without a grep filter and scanning every process for something that might be graphics related.

Second, and this is specific to StumpWM, I found out it's possible to use `ctrl-alt-f<n>` to switch to a different tty and then use `export DISPLAY=:0` to allow access to StumpWM through `stumpish` and then do troubleshooting.